# Issues in creating jobs of size XL in Watson Machine Learning (WML)

Tags: ibm-watson, data-science-experience

I have an issue when trying to create jobs for Decision Optimization when using size XL in Watson Machine Learning (WML). The first job for the day I have no issues what so ever to create. But the second job is failing.

If changing to smaller instance (S or M) there is no issue to start a new job. But for size XL I can not start a second job. I can not find out why. Any ideas?

**I get the following fault codes:**

Code:
error_in_instance_creation

Message:
Instance creation of t-shirt-size XL and type do12.10 failed.

Answer (score 0):

We encountered the same issue; for us it had to to with the facts that we did not properly remove our old models / deployments / jobs. After cleaning up all left-over resources accordingly, we were able to startup an instance again.

Comment: Aha. Thanks a lot. That means we will need to clean out all old deployements before doing any new? So just one model deployed at a time? I will test and come back with info if someone needs it in future. Thanks

Comment: I am not an expert in this matter, but for use we can have multiple deployments (at least with S / M) at the same time, but at a certain point in time we had > 50, which was causing creation errors as you describe ..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your support. We have now found out that it seems like IBM has updated the service.

Without doing any changes it is now possible to deploy multiple models in a day and execute the one you are interested in.

So I would say it solved it self